# Update statement to Oracle failing in SSIS Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have to execute some Update statements from SSIS to Oracle which I cannot put into a stored Proc. This statement runs fine in Oracle, but I get error when executing from SSIS. I am using an Execute SQL Task with properties SQL Source Type = Direct Input, BypassPrepare = True. On executing the task, it just hangs for 20 minutes or so. Then I clicked on stop debugging.

```
UPDATE   Table1 R
  SET   R.Column1 =
           (SELECT   SUM (Column2)
              FROM   Table2 M

             WHERE                                
                  M.Column3 IS NULL AND M.Column4 = R.Column4)
WHERE   EXISTS (  SELECT   Column4 AS Column4
                    FROM   Table2 M

                   WHERE                          
                        M.Column3 IS NULL AND M.Column4 = R.Column4
                GROUP BY   Column4)   `
```

Comment: No Error, it just does not complete processing

Comment: Also, on the Execution Results Page, I see Warning: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: "but I get error when executing from SSIS"  You're probably just blocking which is why it's taking 20 minutes.  Something else it updating when you attempt to update.  Use the actual Oracle DLLs if possible instead of the MS versions.  I found that they are better... rather I have less problems.

Comment: Can you send me an example of how to "Use the actual Oracle DLLs if possible instead of the MS versions". I am not sure what you mean. I even tried a simple statement like UPDATE   Table1 R   SET   R.Column1 =1 . This hangs as well. UPDATE   Table1 R   SET   R.Column1 =1; (note the semicolon) straightaway fails. so does UPDATE   Table1 R   SET   R.Column1 =1; commit ; and UPDATE   Table1 R   SET   R.Column1 =1 (on a new line) commit

Answer (score 3):

When this happened to me, it was because I had left a transaction open. I had been using SQL Developer to reset column values in the target table during testing. (SQL Developer doesn't use implicit transactions by default.)

Here's the detail:

[SSIS PL/SQL task hangs with message “Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors.”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/ssis-pl-sql-task-hangs-with-message-multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-er)

Comment: THANKS!!! that was what happened to me.... It was driving me nuts figuring this out!